# C2248 error while porting ICU VS2013 solution to VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, icu

I am trying to port ICU 4.0 VS2013 solution to VS2015, while porting I get following error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2248   'icu_4_0::Format::Format': cannot access protected member declared in class 'icu_4_0::Format'   i18n    c:\research\releases\gtlib\gtlib_6.0\source\aglc\aglc40\source\i18n\unicode\measfmt.h   72

this is how function is defined:

```
protected:

/**
 * Default constructor.
 * @stable ICU 3.0
 */
MeasureFormat();
```

and class is defined as follows

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MeasureFormat : public Format {
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing the error.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this Bug base class(Format) was causing problem, base class must have copy constructor as well as assignment operator both should be public, It wasn't working when they were protected (atleast in my case).

[C2248 error when using promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639515/c2248-error-when-using-promise)